# Google BigQuery API (Python client Library) > Querying data (asynchronous)

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I'm following `Python Client Libraries for the Google BigQuery API` - https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/bigquery/usage.html#jobs > **Querying data (asynchronous)**

when it comes to Retrieve the results, executing the code:

```
rows, total_count, token = query.fetch_data()  # API requet
```

always return `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)`
(btw I think there's a typo, it should be `results.fetch_data()` instead!)

However, the following code works fine

```
results = job.results()
rows = results.fetch_data()
tbl = [x for x in rows]
```

All the rows of the table are return (as list of tuples) in tbl in a singel shot, >225K rows!

Can anyone why I get the error, or is there anything wrong in the doc?

How can I still retrieve results in batches (iterating through page by page)

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A while ago i opened [this issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/3576) asking for updating the docs but as you can see from the answers it still requires official release to change.

Please refer to the [code base](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/master/core/google/cloud/iterator.py) itself for better docstring (in this case specifically the class Iterator):

```
"""Iterators for paging through API responses.
These iterators simplify the process of paging through API responses
where the response is a list of results with a ``nextPageToken``.
To make an iterator work, you'll need to provide a way to convert a JSON
item returned from the API into the object of your choice (via
``item_to_value``). You also may need to specify a custom ``items_key`` so
that a given response (containing a page of results) can be parsed into an
iterable page of the actual objects you want. You then can use this to get
**all** the results from a resource::
    >>> def item_to_value(iterator, item):
    ...     my_item = MyItemClass(iterator.client, other_arg=True)
    ...     my_item._set_properties(item)
    ...     return my_item
    ...
    >>> iterator = Iterator(..., items_key='blocks',
    ...                     item_to_value=item_to_value)
    >>> list(iterator)  # Convert to a list (consumes all values).
Or you can walk your way through items and call off the search early if
you find what you're looking for (resulting in possibly fewer
requests)::
    >>> for my_item in Iterator(...):
    ...     print(my_item.name)
    ...     if not my_item.is_valid:
    ...         break
At any point, you may check the number of items consumed by referencing the
``num_results`` property of the iterator::
    >>> my_iterator = Iterator(...)
    >>> for my_item in my_iterator:
    ...     if my_iterator.num_results >= 10:
    ...         break
When iterating, not every new item will send a request to the server.
To iterate based on each page of items (where a page corresponds to
a request)::
    >>> iterator = Iterator(...)
    >>> for page in iterator.pages:
    ...     print('=' * 20)
    ...     print('    Page number: %d' % (iterator.page_number,))
    ...     print('  Items in page: %d' % (page.num_items,))
    ...     print('     First item: %r' % (next(page),))
    ...     print('Items remaining: %d' % (page.remaining,))
    ...     print('Next page token: %s' % (iterator.next_page_token,))
    ====================
        Page number: 1
      Items in page: 1
         First item: <MyItemClass at 0x7f1d3cccf690>
    Items remaining: 0
    Next page token: eav1OzQB0OM8rLdGXOEsyQWSG
    ====================
        Page number: 2
      Items in page: 19
         First item: <MyItemClass at 0x7f1d3cccffd0>
    Items remaining: 18
    Next page token: None
To consume an entire page::
    >>> list(page)
    [
        <MyItemClass at 0x7fd64a098ad0>,
        <MyItemClass at 0x7fd64a098ed0>,
        <MyItemClass at 0x7fd64a098e90>,
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! this really clarified things :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct about the document. There is a typo -

`results = job.results()`

`rows, total_count, token = query.fetch_data()  # API requet`

`while True:`

```
    do_something_with(rows)

     if token is None:

          break

    rows, total_count,token=query.fetch_data(page_token=token)       # API requeste here
```

For the big dataset we do hourly query to fetch the data in our daily job.